# Include and Extend a use case model

Tags: uml

Suppose there are two use cases A and B. 
Is the below scenario even possible:

```
A includes B and at the same time B extends A?
```

Can someone explain this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A includes B and at the same time B extends A is not possible.

A includes B means that usecase B is always included during usecase A. B is a mandatory part of A.

B extends A means that usecase A may (or may not) be extended by usecase B. A is the core/main/principal usecase and B is  one possible addition of A but it is not mandatory.

Hoping it is clear....

Comment: Suppose there is a functionality that is at one point mandatory (say, at the initial point of the app) but then later it is optional. How can we represent this?